# i want to search in codeigniter and view result is which i searched

Tags: codeigniter, search

Here is my Model:

```
function get_search() {
  $match = $this->input->post('search');
  $this->db->like('p_category',$match);
  $this->db->or_like('p_place',$match);
  $this->db->or_like('p_price',$match);
  $query = $this->db->get('tbl_property');
  if($query->num_rows() > 0)
         return $query->result();
    else
         return FALSE;
}
```

Here is my View:

```
<?php 
        foreach($query as $pack_details): 
    ?>
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
            <?php echo $pack_details->p_title?>
        </table>
    <?php 
    endforeach;?>
```

want to search and will show result only which i searched.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old one of mine, but you may be able to adapt it to yours. Your form sends the post to the controller. The variable $art is the search item. The variable $num is the number of results. The jquery sends the form to the article class search_results

Controller

```
public function seek()
{
    // this is the artist search display
  $art = html_escape(trim($this->input->post('art')));
  $this->db->like('artist', $art);
  $this->db->select('artist, song, album, mix_name');
  $query = $this->db->get('podcasts');
  $num = $query->num_rows();
  echo "<h3>We found $num $art song's</h3>";
  if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
         echo "<li class='search_list'>Song: $row->song <br> Album: $row->album <br> Podcast: $row->mix_name</li> ";
     }
  }else {
      echo "You searched for $art, Please check your spelling, or ensure the artists name is complete";
    }
}
```

Jquery if you want the search to show up on the same page

```
$(function () {
"use strict";
$("#search").submit(function () {
    var data = $('#search').serialize();
    //alert(data); return false;
    $.ajax({
        url: "/display/seek",
        data: data,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (msg) {
            $('article.search_results').html(msg).show();
        }
    });
    return false;
 });
});
```

View is simply. See the last line in the jquery

```
<article class="search_results"></article>
```